# Python partial string mapping to value from list

Tags: python, list, mapping

Given list A:

```python
['cheese', 'spam', 'sausage', 'eggs']
```

and list B:

```python
['cz', 'sp', 'sg', 'eg']
```

i would like to get the code from list B for a string containing a word from list A.

I.e. for a string like `something about cheese` I would like to get the code `cz` from list B. It is guaranteed that only one item from list A occurs in the input string.

How can this be achieved without checking for each condition? I.e. what would be a better way to do it instead of:

```python
s = 'something about cheese'

if 'cheese' in s:
    return 'cz'
if 'spam' in s:
    return 'sp'
if 'sausage' in s:
    return 'sg'
...
```

Comment: `for a,b in zip(listA, listB): if a in s: return b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` them together and iterate through the A's until one is in the string. Then return the corresponding B.

```
def foo(someString, listA, listB):
    for a,b in zip(listA, listB):
        if a in someString:
            return b

someString = "something about cheese"
listA = ['cheese', 'spam', 'sausage', 'eggs']
listB = ['cz', 'sp', 'sg', 'eg']
print(foo(someString, listA, listB))  # => cz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mapping = {
    'cheese': 'cz',
    'spam': 'sp',
    'sausage': 'sg',
    'eggs': 'eg'
}

s = 'something about cheese'

for key, value in mapping.iteritems():
    if key in s:
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like this:

```
for i, key in enumerate(list_a):
    if key in s:
        return list_b[i]
```

or

```
for key, value in zip(list_a, list_b):
    if key in s:
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List_A = ['cheese', 'spam', 'sausage', 'eggs']
List_B = ['cz', 'sp', 'sg', 'eg']

s = 'something about cheese'

SplitWordsList = s.split ( " " ) # Separate the words in the sentence

for SplitWord in SplitWordsList :
    if  ( SplitWord in List_A ) :
        return  ( List_B [ List_A.index ( SplitWord ) ] )
        break
```